# Find callers of method from parent interface in java?

Tags: java, interface, call-hierarchy

I would like to list all callers of method from **parent interface only**,
but I cannot find such a feature in both Eclipse and IntelliJ,
Anyone can advise?

< Current Limitation >
Both Eclipse and Intellij's show usage/call hierarchy/show reference will list all callers to child interfaces and parent interface

< Workaround >
My current workaround is just to rename the method name and check compile errors on caller.
But it only works when parent and child interface has the same method, 
so that callers to parent method will have error while callers to child's will not.

> e.g.  interface B extends interface A
>
> A has doX() method, B might have doX() method, too.
>
> Given methodC() calls A.doX(), methodD() calls B.doX()
>
> **Requirement: list only methodC()**

Thanks a lot : )

Comment: Are you talking about looking through source code to see which client code calls it or walking up a runtime stack trace to see where an invocation came from?

Comment: Static trace on source code only

Comment: I can't speak for IntelliJ, but on Eclipse, right-click the method and choose References->(your scope).

Comment: Use Eclipse's references result in the same for call hierarchy, it will both show callers to parent interface as well as child interface

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface A {
    void doX();
}
```

Now B,

```
public interface  B extends A{
    void doX(); // this will override method in A
}
```

This may help you to figure out issue in your case.

Comment: Ruchira, maybe I was not stating clearly. I mean how to find caller of A.doX() of existing interface A. :)